# Build Tree multidimensional array from database

Tags: php, mysql

How would I make an infinite recursion loop using php and mysql to build a specific array layout? I have writting out my tables, array layout and my attempt at getting this work. I have spent the last few hours working on this but am having no luck.

I am trying to build a php array based on my database that builds a specific layout when using `json_encode`

My Database tables look like the following

```
TABLE `info`         |    TABLE `relations`
+--------+-----------+    +--------+-----------+
| id     | name      +    | id     | parent_id |
+--------+-----------+    +--------+-----------+
| 2p03Me | sue       |    | b5ET7N | 2p03Me    |
| b5ET7N | john      |    | h7S4bk | b5ET7N    |
| h7S4bk | bob       |    | iMz4d7 | 2p03Me    |
| iMz4d7 | sam       |    | ixRpaH | iMz4d7    |
| ixRpaH | teddy     |    | k41BhX | ixRpaH    |
| k41BhX | dan       |    +--------+-----------+ 
+--------+-----------+
```

The generated array should look something like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => sue
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [text] => john
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [text] => bob
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [text] => teddy
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [text] => dan
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)
```

I have tried this a few times but I can't seem to get this to work. My latest and last attempt was

```
    $tree = category_tree($mysqli, $origSnippet);
    function category_tree($mysqli, $catid, $tree = array()) {
        ?><pre><?php print_r($tree); ?></pre><?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `relations` INNER JOIN `info` ON `relations`.`id`=`info`.`id` WHERE `relations`.`parent_snippet_id`='$catid'";
        $children = $mysqli->query($sql);
        while($child = $children->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tree[] = array('text' => "$child[name]/$child[id]");
            echo "$child[name]/$child[snippet_id]<br/>";
            category_tree($mysqli, $child['id'], $tree);
        }
        return $tree;
    }
```

Any help you may be able to provide would be very appricated.

### ## My Question ##

How would I make an infinite recursion loop using php and mysql to build a specific array layout? I have writting out my tables, array layout and my attempt at getting this work. I have spent the last few hours working on this but am having no luck.

Comment: Tables are `info` and `relations` but the SQL references `forked_snippets` and `snippet_version`? Also, you need a fully recursive query (as in Oracle SQL `start with ... connect by`), which I do not believe MySQL supports at present.  And also you must handle infinite recursion since it's a possibility in your relationship table.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you for the information. Didn't realize I copied the old version before I renamed that tables and fields.

I do realize that I would need to handle for infinite recursion, but I am not sure how I would handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by doing the following:

```
$tree = array();
$node_id = 0;
$origSnippet = "2p03Me"; //THIS IS GOTTEN FROM A SEPERATE FUNCTION BUT WILL BE THE STARTING POINT OF THE LOOP

function hasChildNodes($mysqli, $snippetID) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `relations` INNER JOIN `info` ON `relations`.`id`=`info`.`id` WHERE `relations`.`parent_id`='$snippetID'";
    return $mysqli->query($sql)->num_rows;
}

function buildTree($mysqli, $snippetID, $node_id, &$tree) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `relations` INNER JOIN `info` ON `relations`.`id`=`info`.`id` WHERE `relations`.`parent_id`='$snippetID'";
    $snippets = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while($snippet = $snippets->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tree[$node_id] = Array("text" => $snippet['name']);
        if (hasChildNodes($mysqli, $snippet['id']) >= 1) {
            buildTree($mysqli, $snippet['id'], 0, $tree[$node_id]['nodes']);
        }
        $node_id++;
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `id`='$origSnippet' LIMIT 1";
$origSnippet = $mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();

$tree[$node_id] = Array("text" => $origSnippet['name']);

if (hasChildNodes($mysqli, $childSnippet) >= 1) {
    buildTree($mysqli, $childSnippet, $node_id, $tree[$node_id]['nodes']);
}
```